# How can I locate unbalanced delimiters for error reporting in yacc/bison?

Tags: bison, yacc

I have a grammar which uses parentheses and square brackets as delimiters. When the parser generated by bison is given input with unbalanced delimiters, the error location in the `YYLTYPE*` passed to `yyerror` is the end of the input. So, for example, on input `xx(yy`, within `void yyerror(YYLTYPE* yylloc, Context* ctx, const char* msg)` I have that `yylloc->first_column == yylloc->last_column == 5`. Unfortunately, the end of the input is not the most salient location for indicating an unmatched delimiter. Much more useful would be the position of the left parenthesis or left square bracket for which there was no match. (In the example, that would be the left parenthesis at offset 2.) I gather that that this information is available in the parse stack---there has to be some *n* such that `$-n` is the unmatched `(` or `[` token and `@-n` is the `YYLTYPE` struct holding its position---but none of that appears to be available from `yyerror`. I'm aware that I could keep a stack of my own for tracking the offsets of delimiters and stash that in the `Context` I'm already passing to `yyerror`, but that seems inelegant and duplicative, as bison has already to be tracking this.

So: How can one prise out of bison the position of the first unbalanced delimiter it encounters in input, so that this is available when producing the message for a parse error?

Comment: Could you share your grammar (at least the part of it that is handling parens) ?

Comment: It's [here](https://github.com/uckelman/liblightgrep/blob/ccsetops/src/lib/parser.ypp). Parentheses are handled at line 187.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to add either the rule:

```
atom: '(' error    { /* unmatched left paren at @1 */ }
```

or

```
atom: '(' alt error    { /* unmatched left paren at @1 */ }
```

to get info about unmatched left parentheses.  The difference being that the first rule will match an unmatched parenthesis that is not followed by anything parseable (such as at the end of the input), while the second will only match if it is followed by something that looks like a valid `alt`.

There's possibly an issue if you have any other error productions in your grammar (which you don't in the linked grammar), in which case a different error production might be triggered first.  Since there are no other error rules, the first alternative is better.

Note that using yacc/bison error recovery rules does not in any way suppress the syntax error, it just runs some code AFTER a syntax error to attempt to recover.  That code can print additional error messages and then abort rather than trying to recover, but those messages will be printed after the syntax error message.

Comment: The thing in your answer which solved the problem for me was "Note that using yacc/bison error recovery rules does not in any way suppress the syntax error, it just runs some code AFTER a syntax error to attempt to recover." This made me realize that the action associated with the error rule was never being run, because I throw an exception in `yyerror`. After adjusting for that, I can see that I *do* get matches on the error rule.

Comment: Thanks @chris-dodd and @uckelman! I was doing the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the error token in bison: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Recovery.html#Error-Recovery

I imagine something like this would work (I have not tested):

```
atom:  '(' alt ')'        { $$ = $2; }
    |  '(' alt error '\n' { /* this handles an extra left paren */ }
    |   error alt ')'     { /* this handles an extra right paren */ }
    |   literal
    ;
```

Comment: Hmm. I can't end with a newline, since none of my input does. When I add `| '(' alt error`, that production is never matched. Unmatched left parens end up being regular parse errors as before.

Comment: When you encounter an unmatched left paren, what behavior do you want?  Are you just looking for clean error reporting, or do you want the ability to disregard some input and keep parsing?

Comment: I have no use for actual recovery---I'm not going to continue parsing after an error. All I want is to know the offset of the unmatched left paren. (BTW, I'd already read the section on error recovery and tried it, to see if I could get the offset this way.)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you have two issues that you are trying to solve.  First, you want to know which paren caused the inbalance.  Second, you want to know the line/column of that paren.  Right?

Comment: I don't see how those two things differ. The only thing distinguishing one left parenthesis from any other is its location.

Comment: For left parens, you won't know it's unbalanced until you're well past the input.  So if you want to know what line/column it's at, you need to store that location as part of the token.  When encountering a paren your lexer shouldn't return '(' or ')', but rather a token containing the line/column number.

Comment: I don't *have* the offending token. How will adding a location to tokens (duplicating the YYLTYPE!) help me get the unmatched left parenthesis token in event of error?

Comment: It won't help you find the unmatched paren. But it will help you know the location information for error reporting once you find the unbalanced one.

Comment: You're not getting what I'm saying. Each token already has a location associated with it, in the form of an YYLLTYPE struct. (Location tracking using YYLTYPE is described in [Section 3.6](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracking-Locations) of the Bison docs.) Getting the location of a token is trivial if I already have the token within an action: If the token is `$n`, then `@n` is the YYLTYPE containing the location. The whole reason for this question is that I *don't* have the token for an unmatched left parenthesis within any action, nor do I have it in `yyerror`.

Comment: See my comment above to Chris Dodd. The problem turned out to be not that the error rule wasn't matching, but that the action associated with it never ran due to `yyerror` throwing an exception.